# How to format to n decimal places in Python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a variable `n` and I want to print *n* decimal places.

```
import math
n = 5
print(f"{math.pi:.nf}")
```

`ValueError: Format specifier missing precision`

This doesn't work, but how might it be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fields in format strings [can be nested](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
>>> print(f"{math.pi:.{n}f}")
3.14159
```

Answer (score 5):

For pre-3.6 versions, you can use `.format()`

```
print('{:.{}}'.format(math.pi, n)))
```